# What is the most efficient way to do a wordpress conditional ? if_is versus ! if_is_not

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

What is the most efficient way to do a conditional ?

I'm used to doing conditionals this way -

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { 

// Do things   

else {

return false;

}
```

Is this way more efficient in that in ends early if it's false ?

```
if ( ! is_front_page() ) { 

return false;

} else 

// Do things

{
```

Comment: Define "efficient". "Efficient" in what way? Fastest execution speed? Least amount of characters? Best memory use?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that there's no difference in the code examples you've written, at least efficiency wise.
The condition is basically the same. The question is more a semantic question and I believe that this approach is better:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { 

// Do things   

} else { //YOU FORGOT HERE A CLOSING BRACKET FOR THE IF

return false;

}
```

Furthermore, You can remove the "else" part.
In case the condition returns true then the code will run and finally return true, otherwise - it would return false.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { 

  // Do things   

  return true;

}
return false;
```

Comment: That is… rather debatable. *Fail early* usually leads to cleaner code rather than tacking all the unhappy paths onto the end, especially if you have several nested conditions.

Comment: You're right but following the OP's question I had an hunch it's not the case. @andytc consider elaborating regarding your issue if it's not the case.